# Geometric interpretation of the Banach Mazur distance

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be two isomorphic Banach spaces, and

$$
d(X,Y):=\inf\{\|T\|\|T^{-1}\|: T \textrm{ is an is an isomorphism from $X$ to $Y$} \}
$$

the Banach Mazur distance between $X$ and $Y$. Assuming that $\|T\|=1$, it is easy (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201503/motivation-behind-the-definition-of-banach-mazur-distance)) that this distance is the infimum of the numbers $r\geq 1$ such that

$$
T(U_{X}) \subset U_{Y} \subset r T(U_{X}),
$$

where $U_{X}$ and $U_{Y}$ are, respectively, the closed unit balls of $X$ and $Y$.

I have seen [here](https://www.um.es/summer_school2018/files/pdfs/course_giannopoulos_I.pdf), that the Banach Mazur distance can be interpreted as the infimum of the numbers $r\geq 1$ such that

$$
U_{Y} \subset T(U_{X}) \subset r U_{Y},
$$

Why are true the above inclusions? Maybe it's obvious, but I can't prove it formally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U_Y \subseteq T(U_X)$ says for every $y \in Y$ with $\|y\| \le 1$, there is $x \in X$ with $y = Tx$ and $\|x\| \le 1$.  Since $x = T^{-1} y$, that is equivalent to $\|T^{-1}\|\le 1$.

$T(U_X) \subseteq r U_Y$ says $\|Tx \| \le r$ for every $x \in X$ with $\|x\| \le 1$, i.e.
$\|T\| \le r$.

Thus if there exists isomorphism $T$ with $U_Y \subseteq T(U_X) \subseteq r U_Y$, this isomorphism has $\|T\| \|T^{-1}\| \le r$, and the Banach-Mazur distance $\le r$.

Conversely, if the Banach-Mazur distance is $d$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is
an isomorphism $T$ with $\|T\| \|T^{-1}\| \le d+\epsilon$.  We may assume wlog that 
$\|T^{-1} \| = 1$, and we have $U_Y \subseteq T(U_X) \subset (d+\epsilon) U_Y$.
So the infimum of the numbers $r$ as described is at most $d$.

Comment: Thank you very much!