Prove that $\operatorname{cond}(f ) = \|A^{−1}\|\|A\|.$
Question:
I am trying to prove that the condition number of a function $  f(x) = Ax $, where A $\in R^{m\times n}$ and $x \in R^{n\times 1}$ , is given by:
$$
\text{cond}(f) = \|A^{-1}\|\|A\|
$$
The given definition of the condition number of a function ( f ) is:
$$
    \limsup_{\|\Delta x\| \to 0} \frac{\frac{\|\Delta y\|}{\|y\|}}{\frac{\|\Delta x\|}{\|x\|}}  
$$
Starting from this definition, I have:
$$
    \text{cond}(f) = \limsup_{\|\Delta x\| \to 0} \frac{\frac{\|A\Delta x\|}{\|Ax\|}}{\frac{\|\Delta x\|}{\|x\|}}  
$$
Then, I proceed with the following simplifications:
$$
    \limsup_{\|\Delta x\| \to 0} \frac{\|A\|}{\|A\|} \frac{\|\Delta x\|}{\|x\|}\frac{\|x\|}{\|\Delta x\|}
$$
Next, eliminating ( x ), I arrive at:
$$
    \limsup_{\|\Delta x\| \to 0} \frac{\|A\|}{\|A\|}
$$
Finally, I get:
$$
    \text{cond}(f) = \|A^{-1}\|\|A\|
$$
However, I feel like something is wrong, but I’m not sure what the exact issue is. Could anyone help me identify where my reasoning or steps might be incorrect?

Here is a Mathjax tutorial, you simply need dollar signs for the environment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Can you explain the step "Then, I proceed with the following simplifications:"?

One problem is that your definition says nothing about $x$.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4277644/169085

Sorry that I make plenty mistakes, x is a variable in $R^{n}$.  Also, thanks a lot for the tutorial.

The condition number (at least one of the myriad definitions) determines the relative sensitivity of solutions to $Ay=x$, so you presumably need $f(x) = A^{-1} x$.
One issue with your definition is that $x$ is fixed, so the best we can get is
$\limsup_{h \to 0} { { \|A^{-1} h \|\over \|A^{-1}x\| } \over { \|h\| \over \|x\|} } = \limsup_{h \to 0} { \|A^{-1} h \| \over \|h\| } { \|x\| \over \| A^{-1} x\| } = \|A^{-1} \| { \|x\| \over \| A^{-1} x\| } $.
If you allow $x$ to vary , we get $\sup_{x \neq 0}  \|A^{-1} \| { \|x\| \over \| A^{-1} x\| } = \sup_{w \neq 0}  \|A^{-1} \| { \|Aw\| \over \| w\| } = \|A^{-1}\| \|A\|$.
The term condition number is defined in many different ways, for example, Higham.
